# Bing Map Ajax 7.0 pushpin text not showing

Tags: bing-maps

The text specified for pushpins is not showing on the pin (Bing Maps Ajax 7.0 Control).

Here is the code, virtually copied from the interactive sdk:

```
var offset = new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, 5);
alert($(".LocationPushPin a", $(this)).text());
var pushpinOptions = {text: $(".LocationPushPin a", $(this)).text(), visible: true, textOffset: offset};
var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location($(".RetailLocationLatitude", $(this)).text(), $(".RetailLocationLongitude", $(this)).text(), pushpinOptions));
BingMap.entities.push(pushpin);
```

The alert indeed displays the values ("1001", etc.) that I thought would appear given this code.  No syntax or other errors in Firebug or IE9 debugger.

What am I missing?  Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: I had a misplaced parenthesis (was after options, not after text), which disabled the options feature:

    var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location($(".RetailLocationLatitude", $(this)).text(), $(".RetailLocationLongitude", $(this)).text()), pushpinOptions); 

Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a misplaced parenthesis (was after options:

```
var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location($(".RetailLocationLatitude", $(this)).text(), $(".RetailLocationLongitude", $(this)).text()), pushpinOptions);
```

Sorry for your trouble for having reviewed this question.